# Searching for a specific string at beginnning and end of the line in Vi

Tags: vi

What command is used to search for a specific string at the beginning of line and at the end of the line in vi editor?

Answer (score 11):

To search for `foo` at the beginning or the end of a line:

```
/^foo\|foo$
```

Edit: To avoid retyping the `foo`, you could also use a backreference (suggested by @StéphaneChazelas):

```
/\v(foo)&(^\1|\1$)
```

---

Explanation: To search for `foo` at the beginning of a line you use `/^foo`, while to search for it the end of a line you use `/foo$`. ([Read here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#anchors) for more info.) The escaped "or" delimiter (`|`) checks for either match.

Comment: To avoid having to repeat the `foo`, you can do: `\v(foo)&(^\1|\1$)` (though in this case that ends up being longer to type).

Answer (score 7):

Use <kbd>/</kbd> followed by the appropriate regular expression.

- To search for a string at the start of a line, use `^string` as the expression.
- To search for a string at the end of a line, use `string$` as the expression.

The `^` and `$` characters anchors the expression at the start and end of the line respectively.